# creating multiple columns python

Tags: python

I'm doing web scraping using python. I'm struck with below logic.

I have taken following code from stackoverflow.

```
for url in search('google 1.9.1 python',tld='com.pk',lang ='es',stop = 5):
print(url)
```

so, instead of printing i want to create separate column for each url. example url1, url2, url3, url4, url5. I have coded it as below.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d = {}
>>> doubles = dict()
>>> for url in search('google 1.9.1 python',tld='com.pk',lang ='es',stop = 
5):
doubles = url
```

I know above logic is wrong, but i'm just wondering how can I use dictionaries to create multiple columns ( I have read this in stackoverflow) in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, You want a use dictionary for storing multiple url. So for this:

```
urls = {}
i = 0
for url in enumerate(search('google 1.9.1 python',tld='com.pk',lang ='es',stop = 5)):
      urls[i] = url
      i += 1
```